# Custom Implicit wait in Selenium WebDriver for a loading page to get disappeared

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my application , when I click on any element a waiting image is displayed. I can create an explict wait for waiting that image to get disappeared but I have to write that  after every click code. I want to create a implicit wait. So that I can avoid writing that code every time.

Please help. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a significant difference between *implicit* and *explicit* wait. For finding element explicit wait is always best option. I would suggest write a custom `finElement()` method which has the *explicit* wait baked in so that you do not need to write the explicit wait every time. You do no want to use implicit wait everywhere since if the element is not there it will give performance issue in your test execution.

Comment: can you please give me a example of such a custom findElement() method? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just apply the ["Extract method"](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) refactoring method. Create a separate reusable function/method that aside from clicking an element would wait for an invisibility of the waiting image.

Here is a simple example (should be improved definitely):

```
public void clickAndWait(WebDriver driver, By by) {
    driver.findElement(by).click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("waiting_image")));
}
```

Comment: please elaborate a little bit about "Extract method" refactoring method. Thanks

Comment: @virendrachaudhary added a simple example, hope that at least gives you a starting point.